# Fastest way to create a tilted/successively shifted matrix in numpy

Tags: numpy, optimization, python-3.6

I need to create a (w,N)-matrix that looks like this:

```
w//2............N-1,N-1
.             \     N-1
.              \    N-1
.               \   N-1
1...............N-1,N-1
0...................N-1
00..................N-2
. \                 N-3
.  \                .
.   \               .
000000..............N-w//2
```

Which is an (w,N) matrix, with an odd w. The middle row is the range from 0 to N. For each row index above the middle row, the row is shifted to the left like with [`scipy.ndimage.shift(mode='nearest')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.shift.html) and for each row below the middle row it is shifted to the right with the same method.

N is usually around 10^4 and w is usually between 10 and 10^2.

I've come up with 2 ways to do this:

```
from scipy.ndimage import shift
middle = np.arange(0, N)
final = np.vstack(
    [shift(middle, i, mode='nearest') for i in range(-w//2, 0)] + 
    [middle] + 
    [shift(middle, i, mode='nearest') for i in range(1, w//2)] )
```

Which takes `0.035` seconds to run.

```
np.vstack([
        np.maximum(
            0,
            np.minimum(
                N-1,
                np.arange(-step, N-step)
            )
        )
        for step in range(-w//2, w//2)
    ])
```

Which takes `0.021` seconds to run.

These numbers were with N=10^3 and w=21.

I'd really like to get these numbers down as low as possible, ideally down to around 1ms.

I tried multiprocessing, but that doesn't really help, the overhead to too big to gain something from the concurrency. Also I know I could store this result somewhere, but that'd require a significant change by the caller of this function, so that'll be done later.

Is there any mathematical relation that can represent a tilt/shift operation like this? I couldn't think of one, but if there is, numpy can probably take advantage of that to beat my results.

So yeah, any ideas to make my code faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialise an array with appropriate shape and horizontal values from `0` to `N` (inclusive)

```py
w, N = 11, 10
arr = np.empty(shape= [w, N], dtype= int)
 
arr[:] = np.arange(N)
arr

>>>   [[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]]
```

subtract from each row an appropriate value

```
arr += np.arange(w).reshape([-1, 1])[::-1] - (1+w//2)
arr

>>>   [[ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [-4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]]
```

where values cross limiting values reassign them the limit values

```
arr[arr<0] = 0
arr[arr>N-1] = N-1

arr

>>>   [[5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.],
       [4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.],
       [3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 9., 9., 9.],
       [2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 9., 9.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 9.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]]
```

> Edit

tried timing the script

```
import timeit

script = '''
w, N   = 21, 10**3
arr    = np.empty(shape= [w, N], dtype= int)
arr[:] = np.arange(N)
arr   += np.arange(w).reshape([-1, 1])[::-1] - (1+w//2)

arr[arr<0] = 0
arr[arr>N-1] = N-1
'''

time = timeit.timeit(script, number= 100000, setup= 'import numpy as np') / 100000

time

>>> 0.00019059010320999733    # 0.19 ms
```

Comment: A very nice method.  I expect it's faster than actually shifting the arrays.

Comment: @TlsChris i've benchmarked the script. also if my answer was helpful accept it by clicking on the "tick" besides the upvote button

Comment: I've upvoted it but can't accept it as I didn't ask the question.  Your method is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: @TlsChris oops my bad :P

Comment: Your solution is a bit slower with `0.022` seconds on average, but I do agree that it looks like it'd be great to maintain.

Comment: Nevermind, on average it's just as fast as my solution, but the standard deviation over 1k test runs is only a 6th of my solution for some reason.